# How to change add to cart button text for specific variable products on single page in WooCommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I have a few variable products on my website. Among those only on a few specific products, I have added two variations on those products one is "carbon fiber" and other is "unpainted" now what I want is when user clicks on 2nd variation which is "unpainted" the text of add to cart button should change from "add to cart" button to "made to order. I have updated my question to be more specific
Below is the code First part code is jQuery to display the variations on my single product page and the second to change the name of variations for specific products:

```
 window.addEventListener('load', (event) => {



var initialvalue=jQuery('#pa_choose-option').val();
if(initialvalue=="carbon-fibre")
jQuery('.single_variation_wrap .single_add_to_cart_button').html("Add To 
Cart");

jQuery('#pa_choose-option').on('change', function() {
console.log("here");
var initialvalue=jQuery('#pa_choose-option').val();
if(initialvalue!="carbon-fibre")
jQuery('.single_variation_wrap .single_add_to_cart_button').html("Made 
to Order");
 else
jQuery('.single_variation_wrap .single_add_to_cart_button').html("Add To 
Cart");

});


});


add_filter( 'woocommerce_product_single_add_to_cart_text', 
'custom_addtocart_button_text', 10, 2 ); 
function custom_addtocart_button_text( $button_text, $product ) {
// 1st product
if ( $product->get_id() == 6577 ) {
    $button_text = __( 'jawad', 'woocommerce' );
} 
// 2nd product
elseif ( $product->get_id() == 6570 ) {
    $button_text = __( 'kiani', 'woocommerce' );
}
return $button_text;
}
```

Comment: Hi. Can you be more specific what isn't working? Does jquery select the correct elements? Can you show us the rendered html for this element: '.single_variation_wrap .single_add_to_cart_button'

Comment: @verjas actually I have variations on my single page so what I want is when user clicks on second variation which is "unpainted" the text of add to cart button should change from "add to cart" to "Made to order"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `show_variation` trigger. try the below code.

```
function change_add_to_cart_text_based_on_variation(){
    global $post;
    
    $specific_ids = array( 6594, 6577 );

    if( is_product() && in_array( $post->ID, $specific_ids ) ){
        ?>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            (function($){
                $( ".single_variation_wrap" ).on( "show_variation", function ( event, variation ) {
                    if( variation.attributes['attribute_pa_choose-option'] == 'unpainted' ){
                        jQuery('.single_variation_wrap .single_add_to_cart_button').html( "Made to Order" );
                    }else{
                        jQuery('.single_variation_wrap .single_add_to_cart_button').html( "Add To Cart" );
                    }
                } );

                $( document ).on('click', '.reset_variations', function(event) {
                    event.preventDefault();
                    jQuery('.single_variation_wrap .single_add_to_cart_button').html("Add To Cart");
                });

            })(jQuery);
        </script>
        <?php
    }
}
add_action( 'wp_footer', 'change_add_to_cart_text_based_on_variation', 10, 1 );
```

**Tested and works.**

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much for your reply and help one thing more I want is to do it for specific products. This code is working for all products but I want it to work for only those products which I want by giving product id so how can I add product id's in this code ?

Comment: I have already added code for specific products. see updated.